# Filter dates to show only the current month and 12 months ahead in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a df with some dates and I would like to filter dates to show only the current month and 12 months ahead.

This is my df:
[image]

I would like to keep, for each date in the `Date` column, in the `DataReferencia` column, the dates of the current month and 12 months ahead and then subtract the values from the `Value` column. For the above dates, on the day 2003-01-17, it would be the dates in the `DataReferencia` column 2003-01-01 and 2003-12-01. This df runs from 2003-01 to 2020-12.

I tried this code, but returns an empty df:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

test %>%
  filter(year(DataReferencia) == Data.Ano & month(DataReferencia) == Data.Mes + 11,
         month(DataReferencia) == Data.Mes)
```

My `dput`:

```
structure(list(Instituicao = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Data = structure(c(12069, 12069, 12069, 
12069, 12069, 12069, 12069, 12069, 12069, 12069, 12069, 12069, 
12070, 12070, 12070, 12070, 12070), class = "Date"), DataReferencia = structure(c(12053, 
12084, 12112, 12143, 12173, 12204, 12234, 12265, 12296, 12326, 
12357, 12387, 12053, 12084, 12112, 12143, 12173), class = "Date"), 
    Valor = c(26, 24, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
    26, 24, 22, 22, 22), DataReuniao = structure(c(12073, 12073, 
    12073, 12073, 12073, 12073, 12073, 12073, 12073, 12073, 12073, 
    12073, 12073, 12073, 12073, 12073, 12073), class = "Date"), 
    Reuniao = c(80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 
    80, 80, 80, 80, 80), MetaSelic = c(25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 
    25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 
    25.5, 25.5, 25.5)), row.names = c(NA, 17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What are the values of `Data.Ano` and `Data.Mes`, and where do they come from? Please include these in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to `filter()` for dates where the year & month are the same in `Data` and `DataReferencia`, or the date in `DataReferencia` is 11 months ahead of `Data`. I'm not sure what `Data.Ano` and `Data.Mes` are in your failed code, or if these are translated names of the columns names?

This code will do the job:

```
test %>%
    filter(
        format(DataReferencia, format = '%Y-%m') == format(Data, format = '%Y-%m')
        | format(DataReferencia, format = '%Y-%m') == format(Data + months(11), format = '%Y-%m')
    )


#   Instituicao       Data DataReferencia Valor DataReuniao Reuniao MetaSelic
# 1           1 2003-01-17     2003-01-01    26  2003-01-21      80      25.5
# 2           1 2003-01-17     2003-12-01    22  2003-01-21      80      25.5
# 3           1 2003-01-18     2003-01-01    26  2003-01-21      80      25.5
```

We use `format()` to retrieve the date of the data columns in year-month format; we specify this using `format = %Y-%m`, utilising symbols and abbreviations explained [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Es133/dates.html); basically `%Y` means the (4-digit) year, and `%m` is the (2-digit) month. Because this is still in R-recognised date format, it allows the addition of 11 months in the second condition in `filter()`.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to include these two columns, i'm sorry.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad this solution worked